# Older protocols in Octez mockup mode

Tags: tezos-client, protocol

I need to use the mockup mode in `octez-client` with older protocols, like Delphi. But the current version I have installed (15.1) only has Hangzhou and newer protocols available:

```
$ ./octez-client list mockup protocols
ProtoALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaALphaDdp3zK
PtLimaPtLMwfNinJi9rCfDPWea8dFgTZ1MeJ9f1m2SRic6ayiwW
PtKathmankSpLLDALzWw7CGD2j2MtyveTwboEYokqUCP4a1LxMg
PtJakart2xVj7pYXJBXrqHgd82rdkLey5ZeeGwDgPp9rhQUbSqY
Psithaca2MLRFYargivpo7YvUr7wUDqyxrdhC5CQq78mRvimz6A
PtHangz2aRngywmSRGGvrcTyMbbdpWdpFKuS4uMWxg2RaH9i1qx
```

How can I make the older protocols available in mockup mode? I have been reading [the docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/mockup.html) and [this blog](https://research-development.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-mockup-mode-for-tezos-client.html) and this particular point is not explained. I have also tried to build older versions of Octez (both manually and with Docker) but I run into different issues and I wonder if there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but many Octez client commands are not maintained after a protocol is replaced on mainnet. The commands that are kept are the ones for fetching information from old blocks, these can still be useful on mainnet; all commands for modifying the state of the chain are removed. You can read more about this [here](https://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/howto-freeze-protocols.html). For this reason, the mockup mode of Octez client is not maintained for old protocols because you would not be able to do anything after the activation of the old protocol.

Reverting the freeze commits in the git history of Octez will probably not work and it is probably easier to use old Octez releases.

Comment: Ok, now I understand why they were removed, but I still need them for a research project. In the documentation that you linked it explains what can be deleted. So if I were to revert those changes and recompile Octez from source, would then the protocols become available? Would that be the easiest solution?

Comment: It is unlikely that reverting the freeze commit will work. Using old Octez releases is probably easier.

Comment: If you could add this to your original answer, I will mark it as accepted, then.